# how to select and sum a specific time from start to end timestamp with xarray?

Tags: python-xarray

I hereby ask for your help in python. In fact, I have the NetCDF data from IMERG / GPM (Global precipitation measurement) which has 30 min of temporal resolution and I would like to calculate the sum or aggregations event rainfall on particular dates where I know the start and the end of each date on which I want to aggregate.
I have already tried to do this without success with the resample function for each start timestamp to end timestamp and save it in netcdf file.
I have attached my sript and the .csv file which has the start and end date for each aggregation.

Comment: Hi @mengouna, it would be helpful if you can add some code bits from what you have tried. It will help other contributors to understand the problem and provide the solution sooner

Comment: Dear Ragul thanks you for your help but I don't understand your script well. I want to calculate the sum of each start and end of the specific timestamps, or else calculate the events (consecutive series of rain values greater than zero) of rain then save that on NetCDF                                                                                                          time_begin time_end
1330920000 1330932600
1336944600 1336977000
1337391000 1337394600
1337481000 1337488200
1337628600 1337632200
1338494400 1338507000
1355247000 1355250600


thanks in advance

Comment: My time is irregular so rolling can't be working here is each start and end dates/times I would like to calculate the sum or aggregations event rainfall from each start and end dates below

Datetime_start | Datetime_end
2012-03-05 04:00:00 | 2012-03-05 07:30:00
2012-05-13 21:30:00 | 2012-05-14 06:30:00
2012-05-19 01:30:00 | 2012-05-19 02:30:00
2012-05-20 02:30:00 | 2012-05-20 04:30:00
2012-05-21 19:30:00 | 2012-05-21 20:30:00
2012-05-31 20:00:00 | 2012-05-31 23:30:00

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally not seeing the uploaded files, but your description seems clear enough to me.

I'm not sure the `.resample` method will serve your needs, if your start and ends are arbitrary: resample expects a specific frequency like daily, weekly, or monthly -- see an overview of available frequencies here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

However, it should still be straightforward to do, using xarray's `groupby` and numpy `searchsorted`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("netcdf-data.nc")
df = pd.read_csv("starts-and-ends.csv")
ds["periodnumber"] = ("time", np.searchsorted(df["time"], ds["time"]))
```

Searchsorted will give every timestep a number, e.g.:

```py
period_boundaries = [1, 5, 10]
timesteps = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
print(np.searchsorted(period_boundaries, timesteps))
```

Results in:

```py
[0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]
```

The principle works the same for datetime objects (as long as they can be sorted, and are comparable).

Next, use this variable to group your timesteps and aggregate them:

```py
aggregated = ds["rainfall"].groupby(ds["periodnumber"]).sum("time")
```

This hopefully clarifies the basic idea. Your datasets might not have the same exact variable names, you have to make sure the dates in your csv are parsed properly as dates (e.g. set `parse_dates=True`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), etc.